# Not able to write data to Firestore from IntentService in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, intentservice

My IntentService is responsible for synching the local `SQLite` data to Firebase collection when Wifi network is available, however if I am trying this exact same code from my repository class its working perfectly but not working(Firestore add) from background IntentService.

Below is my code, can anybody help me with this. I'm stuck :(

public class DataSyncService extends IntentService {
    private NotesDao mDao;
    private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;

```
public DataSyncService() {
    super("DataSyncService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    mDao = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), NotesDatabase.class, Constants.DATABASE_NAME)
            .build()
            .getNotesDao();

    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
    if (firebaseApp != null) {
        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(firebaseApp);
        sync();
    }
}

/**
 * Sync the current local persistence data with the network
 */
public void sync() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final List<Notes> offlineData = mDao.fetch();
            for (Notes notes :
                    offlineData) {
                Map<String, Object> note = new HashMap<>();
                note.put(Constants.NOTE_TITLE, notes.getTitle());
                note.put(Constants.NOTE_DESCRIPTION, notes.getDescription());
                note.put(Constants.NOTE_TIMESTAMP, notes.getTimestamp());
                note.put(Constants.NOTE_IMAGE_URL, notes.getImageUri());

                mFirestore.collection(Constants.NOTES_COLLECTION).document(notes.getId()).set(note, SetOptions.merge());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you get any solution?